# Conditioning of a function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Given two integrable random variables $X, Y: \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ on $\mathcal{F}$ with $\sigma(X)\subseteq\sigma(Y)$, what would it be like if we apply conditioning on $\sigma(X)$ (i.e., $X$) to a function $f(X, Y)$? We probably assume that $f(X, Y)$ is measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(Y)$. May we have results like $\mathbb{E}\big[f(X, Y)| X\big]=f\big(X, \mathbb{E}[Y| X]\big)$ almost surely? Further, what it would be like if $f$ is a common function like $f(X, Y)=XY$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x,y)=g(y)$. In this case the conclusion becomes $E[g(Y)|X]=g(E(Y|X)$. Very easy to find counter-examples for this. For example, you can take $g(y)=y^{2}$ and suitable $X,Y$.

For the case $f(X,Y)=XY$ the answer is YES and this follows easily from the fact that you can pull out $X$ from $E[XY|X]$.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $\sigma(X) \subseteq \sigma(Y)$, then $X$ must be independent with itself, so $X$ is a constant. Regardless the counter-example still works.

Comment: @LeanderTilstedKristensen Thanks, I forgot the condition $\sigma(X)\subseteq\sigma(Y)$. But it is  easy to construct a counter-example. In fact, that equality implies (when $g(y)=y^{2}$) that $Y$ is  a.s equal to a $X-$ measurable r.v.